# NOT IN with multiple select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do the following but T-SQL has a problem with how I have multiple select statements within the NOT IN

```
select * from table1 where ParamID not in 
(select paramid from tbl2 
 or 
 select paramid from tbl3 
 or 
 select paramid from tbl3)
```

I get an error: incorrect syntax near select

Is there another way to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: every where clause condition must have both sides of the equation.    Right now you have 1 on the left side and 3 on the right.  ParamID not in (A, B, C)  You could use where ParamID not in () and ParamID not in () and ParamID not in (). a union or not exists.  But why check paramid twice from tbl3?  is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
select t.* 
from table1 t
where not exists (select 1 from tbl2 where paramid = t.paramid) or
      not exists (select 1 from tbl3 where paramid = t.paramid);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION`, like:

```
select * from table1 where ParamID not in 
(select paramid from tbl2 
 UNION 
 select paramid from tbl3 
 UNION
 select paramid from tbl3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
select * from table1 where ParamID not in 
(select paramid from tbl2 
 union all 
 select paramid from tbl3 
 union all 
 select paramid from tbl3)
```